# Multi-variate complexity semplification

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I developed an algorithm with the following multi-variate complexity:
$$O((k^n+kn)l^{kn}),$$
where $n,k,l$ are variables.

I have very little knowledge of complexity theory, and I'm not sure whether this expression can be simplified. Since $k^n$ dominates $kn$ it seems reasonable to $O(k^nl^{kn})$. Is this correct? 
Assuming $l\ge 2$, can the expression be simplified even further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you're right (for $k,n \geq 1$). Also you can right the final answer as $O((kl^k)^n)$.